# UILabel with NSAttributedString ignoring newlines

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a UILabel, the number of lines is set to 0, it is using tail truncation.  The label is sized big enough to fit 2 lines of text.  If I give it a regular NSString with 3 lines of text where each line is short and has \n at the and, it will show the first 2 lines and then an ellipse. It looks like:
Line 1
Line 2...

But if I use an NSAttributedString with the same text, it combines the 2nd and 3rd lines before truncating the result. It looks like:
Line 1
Line 2Line 3

Nothing I've tried short of using CoreText and fixing it line-by-line seems to be able to get this to work correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
```